# Show video when it's loaded (Maximum call stack size exceeded) in VueJs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I trying to implement functionality when user mouse overs the div, some video would be played. I have this components, which is rendered 25 time per page

```
<LocationStripeItemComponent
        v-for="(l, index) in locations" :key="index" :location="l">
</LocationStripeItemComponent>
```

And inside this component, there is following code

```
<template>
<div class="stripe__item card" @mouseover="previewTrailerVideo(true)" @mouseleave="previewTrailerVideo(false)">

    <div class="card__gradient"></div>
    <img :src="location.teaser_image" v-show="!hideImage"
         :alt="location.name" class="card__img"/>

    <div class="card__trailer_loading" v-show="miniTrailerLoading"></div>
    <video v-show="invokeMiniTrailerDiv" autoplay loop class="card__video" id="miniTrailer">
        <source :src="location.teaser_video">
    </video>
</div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
        name: 'LocationStripeItemComponent',
        props: {
            location: {
                type: Object,
                required: true
            }
        },
        data() {
            return {
                invokeMiniTrailerDiv: false,
                miniTrailerLoading: false,
                miniTrailerPlaying: false,
                hideImage: false
            }
        },
        methods: {
            previewTrailerVideo(showState) {
                if (showState) {

                    this.invokeMiniTrailerDiv = true;
                    this.miniTrailerLoading = true;

                    let video = document.getElementById('miniTrailer');
                    if (video.readyState === 4) {
                        this.miniTrailerLoading = false;
                        this.hideImage = true;
                        this.miniTrailerPlaying = true;
                    } else {
                       setTimeout(this.previewTrailerVideo(showState), 1000);
                    }
                } else {
                    this.invokeMiniTrailerDiv = false;
                    this.miniTrailerLoading = false;
                    this.miniTrailerPlaying = false;
                    this.hideImage = false;
                }
            },
        }
    };
</script>
```

And the error I'm keep getting is

```
Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
    at Object.reactiveSetter [as invokeMiniTrailerDiv] (vue.esm.js?efeb:998)
    at VueComponent.proxySetter [as invokeMiniTrailerDiv] (vue.esm.js?efeb:3300)
    at VueComponent.previewTrailerVideo (LocationStripeItemComponent.vue?2f13:93)
    at VueComponent.previewTrailerVideo (LocationStripeItemComponent.vue?2f13:102)
    at VueComponent.previewTrailerVideo (LocationStripeItemComponent.vue?2f13:102)
    at VueComponent.previewTrailerVideo (LocationStripeItemComponent.vue?2f13:102)
    at VueComponent.previewTrailerVideo (LocationStripeItemComponent.vue?2f13:102)
    at VueComponent.previewTrailerVideo (LocationStripeItemComponent.vue?2f13:102)
    at VueComponent.previewTrailerVideo (LocationStripeItemComponent.vue?2f13:102)
    at VueComponent.previewTrailerVideo (LocationStripeItemComponent.vue?2f13:102)
```

I think the problem lies here:

```
setTimeout(this.previewTrailerVideo(showState), 1000);
```

because recursive function is called too many times, but I don't know how else can I get my video element, since is hidden before someone add mouse over the element. Is there some other way to detect when element is visible on page? How to properly implement this functionality? Tank you!

Comment: You need a mouseover event. Check this [example](https://codepen.io/intotheprogram/pen/ZjxZdg)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Problem 1**

The way you use `setTimeout` is incorrect.

The first argument that should be passed to `seTimeout` should be a function. In your code, you are passing `undefined`:

```
setTimeout(this.previewTrailerVideo(showState), 1000);
```

Because the function `previewTrailerVideo` returns nothing, meaning `undefined`.

In other words, your `setTimeout` is not running at all. Meaning, the error that you get is not from the `setTimeout`.

**Problem 2**

The error that you get, is actually from the way you use `setTimeout` (but not `setTimeout` itself). In the same line:

```
setTimeout(this.previewTrailerVideo(showState), 1000);
```

Although the `setTimeout` is not properly called, your recursion works perfectly fine (which is where the error arises), because in that line you are actually **calling** your function, again and again, when `showState === true`.

**Solution**

Simply edit that line into:

```
setTimeout(this.previewTrailerVideo.bind(this, showState), 1000);
```

Read about [`.bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind) for details.

In short, `.bind` method will not call your function, but will pass arguments into your function and return your function with those arguments already inside.

By using `.bind`, you are now passing your supposed function into `setTimeout` (problem 1), and also stop recursing (problem 2).

Comment: Ah, didn't know that! Thank you!